# Долгий этот путь(,) или повернуть?

Tags: запятые

Нужна эта запятая в «Долгом пути» Боярского?

> Долгий этот путь(,) или повернуть?

Comment: Нужно писать предложение полностью, от этого зависят знаки. "Долгий этот путь, или повернуть, ждёт ли кто-нибудь?"

Comment: А зачем? Обе части вопросительные.